# Error in GraalVM Context when using ES6 module imports

Tags: javascript, java, ecmascript-6, graalvm

I'm attempting to use GraalVM version 20.1.0 for Java 8 (graalvm-ce-java8-windows-amd64-20.1.0) to run some ES6 JavaScript from within Java. I'm using `Context` like this:

```
try (final Context jsContext = Context.newBuilder("js").allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
    final URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("index.js");
    final File file = Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
    final Source source = Source.newBuilder("js", file).mimeType("application/javascript+module").build();
    final Value value = jsContext.eval(source);

    System.out.println(value);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The JS files I'm using look like this:

```
// index.js
import testFn from "./testFn";
testFn; // return value to Java
```

---

```
// testFn.js
function testFn() {
    print("Test!");
}

export default testFn;
```

---

Running this I get the *very* undescriptive error `

```
Exception in thread "main" Error: C:/path/to/testFn.js
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:345)
    // This error points to "final Value value = jsContext.eval(source);" in the Java code
```

However if I run `testFn.js` directly by replacing `index.js` with `testFn.js` in the Java code it works fine! It also works fine if I remove the import, so I assume something is buggy with ES6 imports. Renaming the files to use `*.mjs` extension makes no difference. Adding `allowIO(true)` to the `Context` config also changes nothing.

All of the code above is a MVCE that you can test, if needed.

---

I get the same error if I try to import a non-existent file as well (`import "./asdasd"`) so perhaps it's just not finding the file. Although I have double-checked that the file exists in the directory it lists so perhaps that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the file extension when importing in `GraalVM`:

```
import testFn from "./testFn.js"; // needs '.js' after file name!
testFn;
```

Note that the index file itself needs to have either the `.mjs` file extension, not `.js`, **OR** you need to use `.mimeType("application/javascript+module")` for imports to work. The files you import, however, do not need a specific file extension.

I have identified this as a bug and have made a [bug report here](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2564). Future readers check the link to see if this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As I see (but not perfectly sure), GraalVM's `Context.eval(Source source)` method works the same way how JavaScript's `eval()` function does.

That can cause the problem, as JS `eval` always treats its input as a Script, not as a Module, and static `import`s are allowed only inside Modules.

You could try to use the dynamic `await import('./testFn')` syntax instead, which is allowed inside Scripts as well (if GraalVM supports it), but unfortunately I can't tell if it will work, and I don't know how to pass back asynchronous resources to Java.

Comment: Dynamic import seem to be allowed, but that also gives the same error unfortunately: `Promise{[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: Error: C:\path\to\testFn.js}` Nice idea though, I didn't even know dynamic imports were a thing in JS!

Comment: @Charanor Then I think I can't help. I'm not familiar with Graal and not advanced in Java...

Comment: I just realised that I get the exact same error if I try to import a non-existent file (`import "./asdasdasd"`) so I'm thinking maybe it's just not finding the file. Although it definitely exists in the directory it lists. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Solved it! Apparently you **need** to specify the the file extension of the file you're importing in GraalVM.